# OpenVpn & KVM: can't access LAN behind server

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, kvm-virtualization, route

i just set up an OpenVPN Server on a rented root Server. I can ping the OpenVPN Server IP, but can't connect or ping to other Machines (VMs) on the OpenVPN Server Network.
According to the official OpenVPN doku i added "push route" to the server.conf to enable access to other Machines on the Server Network.

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert ex1.crt
key ex1.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

ifconfig from the openvpn server:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:e6:d9:07:46:c2  
          inet addr:148.251.139.133  Bcast:148.251.139.133  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::60e6:d9ff:fe07:46c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2899368 (2.8 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:9b:a0:7d  
          inet addr:148.251.139.133  Bcast:148.251.139.159  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:210:4384::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::468a:5bff:fe9b:a07d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6908929 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:52446354 (52.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:47236296 (47.2 MB)  TX bytes:47236296 (47.2 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:672 (672.0 B)  TX bytes:728 (728.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:76:9b:d5  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:41733 (41.7 KB)  TX bytes:45532 (45.5 KB)

virbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:4c:37:b5  
          inet addr:10.10.10.1  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:370903 (370.9 KB)  TX bytes:197319 (197.3 KB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:15:93:50  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe15:9350/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:45611 (45.6 KB)  TX bytes:3938924 (3.9 MB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:ff:e6:3e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feff:e63e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:402515 (402.5 KB)  TX bytes:4090711 (4.0 MB)
```

The machine on the server network which i try to connect is a KVM VM and has got the IP: 10.10.10.2. I can ping 10.10.10.1 (IP of the virbr1).
Ipv4 forwarding on the ovpn/kvm Server is enabled. While testing i also deactivate the ufw firewall of the ovpn server and of the VM.

If i ping 10.10.10.2 from the ovpn client i get the following tcpdump(tun0) on the server:

> 11:54:46.002533 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.10.10.2: ICMP echo request, id 17629,
>   seq 0, length 64 11:54:46.002602 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP
>   10.10.10.2 protocol 1 port 10088 unreachable, length 92

while tcpdump of the virbr1 bridge(network of the vm: 10.10.10.2) doesn't show anything at all.
I'm assuming, that the openvpn server doesn't forward the packets to virbr1.

routes of the openvpn server:

```
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask       
Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         148.251.139.129 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
148.251.139.128 148.251.139.129 255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 eth0
148.251.139.128 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
148.251.164.152 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.153 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.154 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.155 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.156 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.157 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.158 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
148.251.164.159 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

routes on the vm client:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I'm really stuck with this problem and it would be really nice to be able to understand the problem and then be able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved:

The problem was a misconfiguration in libvirt. The virtual bridge was configured in isolated mode, after switching to routed virtual network and adding the route: 10.8.0.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1 to the VM guests everything worked as expected.